# Values of Select2 in XPages

Tags: listbox, xpages

I have select2 component which works fine related to a listbox. 
My problem is I have 4600 values in Listbox and When i would like to search some values in it It takes too much time to load? Values come from a second column of categorized view. View has 2 Columns. The first one is categorized (4 category) and second column has values almost 4600. When i work less then 100-200 record It works very well. The way I would like to is to make search fastest and get values fastest.

Best Regards
C.A.

```
<xp:listBox id="Parca_1" value="#{document1.Parca_1}">
<xp:selectItems id="selectItems3">
                                                                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var sKey = document1.getItemValueString("Locations");
var vName = "(viewCtgrzAll)";
var rList:Array=new Array();
if (sKey!="")
{
    var nav:NotesViewNavigator = database.getView(vName).createViewNavFromCategory(sKey);
    var entry:NotesViewEntry = nav.getFirst();
    while (entry != null && !entry.isTotal()) 
    {
        if (!entry.isCategory())
        {
            rList.push(entry.getColumnValues()[1])
        }
        var tmpentry:NotesViewEntry = nav.getNextSibling(entry);
            entry.recycle();
            entry = tmpentry;
    }
return rList.sort(function (a, b) {return a.localeCompare(b);});
}
}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:selectItems>
</xp:listBox>
```

Comment: I suggest you take a look at bootstrap4xpages.com and download the Select2 controls.  A Java library is included that will make a full-text search and return the first 50 results to the Select2 control.  It has very fast type-ahead even with 5000+ names in the directory.

Comment: I think I need to download .js and .css files then i will upload related files in to WEBContent folder. When i include as source in any of my XPages select2 plugin will work very well. Or I need to download then install as a Control into My Designer? just like Extension Lİbrary, POI4XPages, The Jquery Project Library?

Comment: Using the bootstrap4xpages\demo.nsf db, you can choose what you'd like to port over to your db.  The bs4xp template store the main bs4xp js script in the Code/Script Libraries folder (bootstrap4xpages.js), client-side JS libraries in the WEB-INF folder (select2-3.4.0), and .java in the Code/Java folder (NamesDataStore.java), and style sheets in the Resources/Style Sheets folder.  You can discern from that what you need.